# Filling a datagrid on a form in VB with values from a MySql Database

Tags: mysql, vb.net

So I am trying to fill a DataGrid called DataGrid which exists on a form with values from a queryon my database. I am having trouble putting the data into this DataGrid. I have the following code so far:

```
   Private Sub Form9_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles  MyBase.Load
    NoMovies.Visible = False
    DataGrid.Visible = False
    Dim query As String
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter
    MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection
    Dim Reader As MySqlDataReader
    'another query and a two table join'
    query = "SELECT movie_id, movie_name from movie2 Where movie_id=(SELECT movie_id from rental where client_username='" & currentUser & "' AND start_date<='" & DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & "' AND return_date>='" & DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & "')"
    MysqlConn.ConnectionString ="server=mysql.scss.tcd.ie;userid=murpha83;password=gh8ht6789;database=murpha83_db"
    MysqlConn.Open()
    Command = New MySqlCommand(query, MysqlConn)
    Reader = Command.ExecuteReader
    da = New MySqlDataAdapter(query, MysqlConn)
    da.Fill(ds)
    da.Fill(DataGrid)
    If Reader.HasRows = True Then
        DataGrid.Visible = True
    Else
        NoMovies.Visible = True
    End If
    MysqlConn.Close()
    Reader.Close()
End Sub
```

I know that the MySql statement works so the problem is just with the DataGrid. The problem is where I try to fill DataGrid with the values from da. I alternatively tried

```
 'DataGrid.DataSource = ds.Tables("movie_name")
```

as movie_name is the column I want but this didn't work either! Any hlep would be great! Thanks!

Comment: `this didn't work` is not a good problem description.  `da.Fill(DataGrid)` I am not sure what DataGrid is, but that is not how to fill one.  Use the adapter to fill a datatable, assign the DT as the DataSource

Comment: I do this all of the time using MySQL and DataGridViews, but I do not use a data adapter. I read in my data directly into an array and then I populate my grid manually using the array. It is a bit more code than using the adapter, but I like having total control over my grid and what is displayed and how it is displayed. If you're interested in an alternative to the data adapter, I'll post the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
da.Fill(DataGrid)
```

With

```
DataGrid.DataSource=ds.Tables[0]
```

Comment: So I've implemented this and now there is no errors in my code but when I run it the DataGrid in my form remains empty? Any reason why this would happen?

Comment: Also need to Add `DataGrid.DataBind()` method after initializing grid

Comment: When I do this I get an error, stating DataBind is not a member of DataGrid. Do I need to write this method? Or import a package?

Comment: I have Updated my Ans

Comment: Thanks for the update but Tables[0] produces an error?